Bluetooth stops working after sleep windows 11
70-80% of the time, after I wake my computer from sleep, I don't have the Bluetooth working.
It disappears from here:

In the device manager, I have to check View => Show Hidden Devices to see it.
I have tried to:

Turn off Windows fast-startup (see comments, there might be something that was turned off correctly)
Update Bluetooth drivers (through Windows and by downloading the latest available ones)
Uninstall / install the devices
Action > Scan for hardware changes.
Stop and re-run the Bluetooth services
Check if there were any Windows updates, there aren't, I'm up to date
Uninstall everything that is Bluetooth-related that is listed in Programs & Features
Use the Windows troubleshooter (it says my computer does not have Bluetooth):

Run SFC And DISM Scans
Disable "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" for the Bluetooth in the Device Manager


I have noticed that there are devices that failed here:

It says "Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems (Code 43)".
I tried disabling, updating, etc ... on those, but nothing worked.

The only solution is to restart my computer but then, the problem arises again when I put my computer to sleep.

I do not have any VM (OracleVM, etc ...) currently running.
This is my version of Windows:

OS Name   Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
Version   10.0.22631 Build 22631

Here is additional information about my hardware:

System Model  B650 EAGLE AX
System Type   x64-based PC
System SKU    Default string
Processor AMD Ryzen 9 7900 12-Core Processor, 3701 Mhz, 12 Core(s), 24 Logical - Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends International, LLC. F5c, 22/04/2024


In addition to using net stop "Bluetooth Support Service" && net start "Bluetooth Support Service", in effect what you've tried, you might do the same for * Radio Management Service (RmSvc)*. Also consider changing Power Options for network/Bluetooth card when sleeping. This does seem to be a persistent issue with Windows from v. 7, at least, and also involves losing WiFi connectivity.

I get this:
C:\Windows\System32>net stop "Radio Management Service (RmSvc)" && net start "Radio Management Service (RmSvc)" The service name is invalid. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.

Ah, do you mean unchecking "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"?

Yes, and perhaps other Power Options settings. Not sure if it will help, but worth trying each applicable setting.

Update, this didn't work, the problem came back :/

powercfg /a says The following sleep states are available on this system:
Standby (S3)
Hibernate
Fast Startup
The following sleep states are not available on this system:
Standby (S1)
The system firmware does not support this standby state.
Standby (S2)
    The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
    The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Hybrid Sleep
    The hypervisor does not support this standby state.


I don't understand why it says "Fast Startup" is available because I have it unchecked here (https://i.imgur.com/b2NF6zk.png). This might be the cause of the problem?

It said "Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43). A request for the USB device descriptor failed" in Device status for the unknown device. Note that when Bluetooth works, this isn't there.

What is the name of the bluetooth device, driver version, and hardware id (eg USB\VID_0BDA&PID_B008&REV_0200)?

Driver version: 10.0.22621.2506. Bluetooth Device : RFCOMM Protocol TDI. Hardware ID:  BTH\MS_RFCOMM

The item "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is not available for ratio devices in Windows 10/11 for a few years already. And it just disables the power management, was not letting a laptop going to sleep normally, when it was available. It was not a solution, but just an extension of agony.
I had this problem on Sony Vaio-Z made in 2010, I had it on HP Envy 13" (2019) and on HP Pavilion 13"(2021), and on HP EliteBook 14", and on ASUS x79 Deluxe desktop motherboard, and on another Gygabyte motherboard. This issue persists for decades, and it is not vendor-related.
